# Command line installation of foldingathome does not work under Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: installation

I followed the instructions here to install foldingathome client, control and viewer: https://foldingathome.org/support/faq/installation-guides/linux/manual-installation-advanced/. However it did raise an error:

`Dependency is not satisfiable: python-support (>= 0.90.0)`

Answer (score 0):

After checking the links I realized version 7.4.4 is rather old and the document hasn't been updated in a long time. Just use the official download links which currently provide version 7.6.13. This instantly fixes the problem.

E.g. `wget https://download.foldingathome.org/releases/public/release/fahclient/debian-stable-64bit/v7.6/fahclient_7.6.13_amd64.deb`

Opened an issue, this might be fixed in the future: https://github.com/FoldingAtHome/fah-issues/issues/1535